# How to read XML output using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read an `XML` output listed below:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
   [merchant] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [merchant-id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
            [merchant-name] => Snip-Its
            [merchant-category] => Hair
            [merchant-website] => www.snipits.com
        )

    [store] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [store-id] => 173DFBB7-67F6-DE11-AD5B-0026B953348A
            [store-name] => Heb
            [store-number] => 0109
        )

    [coupon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [coupon-id] => 385748
            [coupon-address] => 14096 Memorial Drive
            [coupon-city] => Houston
            [coupon-state] => TX
        )
)
```

using `PHP` script as follows but I get a value of '0':

```
foreach( $data->coupons as $mycoupon ) {    
      $address = $mycoupon->coupon->coupon-address;     
    //print_r($mycoupon); 
}
```

So, please help me to understand how to read the values of `SimpleXMLElement` Object and assign them to a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain characters that are not permitted for PHP's naming convention such as a hyphen. To deal with this just enclose the element name in braces as a string as such:

```
$address = $mycoupon->coupon->{'coupon-address'};
```

Give that a try.